# Java Bean Validation 2.0 Hibernate Validator - Executable JAR with external XML-Configuration

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, jsr380

**Context**

I'm developing a stand-alone application that reads input-data from a csv-file.
Until now I've used a self-written class to perform input validation,
and the method used for validating a single record from the input file was triggered 
immediately after reading a single line. The method was called in the methode for reading the csv-file.

Since the input data will be retrieved by using RESTful Web Services in the future
and we'll forfeit using csv-files, I want to decouple the validation from the csv-reading.

I stumpled upon Bean Validation (JSR 380) and used Hibernate Validator to refactor the validation procedure.

I tried both, adding validation-annotations directly to the Bean class, and using a validation.xml file for configuration.
Both ways work when I run the application from Eclipse.

**Problem**

The application will be deployed as an executable JAR.
I would like to keep the option to change the validation constraints without the need to repack and redeploy the JAR.
So I'm trying to figure out, if there is a way to exclude the `validation.xml` (+ further configuration files) from the JAR and put it in some directory "close" to the JAR.
Something like this:

```
myApp/
 |-- JAR
 |-- conf/
     |-- ValidationMessages.properties
     |-- META-INF/
          |-- validation.xml
          |-- validation/
               |-- constraints-myBean.xml
```

**What I tried**

1. Placing the `META-INF/`-folder in the same directory as the JAR

   > *The JAR runs, but the validation doesn't work.*
2. Referencing the absolute path to `constraints-myBean.xml` in `validation.xml`, specifically changing
   `<constraint-mapping>META-INF/validation/constraints-pbpRecord.xml</constraint-mapping>`
   to
   `<constraint-mapping>C:/path/to/myApp/META-INF/validation/constraints-pbpRecord.xml</constraint-mapping>`
   and including `validation.xml` in my JAR.

   > *A* `ValidationException` *cancels the execution:*

```java
Exception in thread "main" javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000096: Unable to open input stream for mapping file C:/Users/wsteffler/Desktop/pbp_import_tool/pbp_orgunit_import/META-INF/validation/constraints-pbpRecord.xml.  
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationBootstrapParameters.setMappingStreams(ValidationBootstrapParameters.java:291)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationBootstrapParameters.<init>(ValidationBootstrapParameters.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.AbstractConfigurationImpl.parseValidationXml(AbstractConfigurationImpl.java:595)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.AbstractConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(AbstractConfigurationImpl.java:376)
        at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:103)
        at de.uniwuppertal.hisinone.orgunitimport.pbp.Main.main(Main.java:220)
```

3. Adding the parent-directory of `META-INF/` to the classpath (with `-classpath` argument)

   > *The JAR runs, but the validation doesn't work.*

I've read the [Bean Validation specification](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/spec) (6.5. Bootstrapping & 9. XML deployment descriptor) and the [Hibernate Validator 6.1.0 Reference Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/) (8. Configuring via XML), especially looking for solutions in the chapters in parentheses, and searched on StackOverflow and Google for solutions. Unfortunately I haven't found anything that would lead me to a solution so far.

Is it even possible to achieve bootstrapping an external `validation.xml` when executing a JAR?
If it is, how can I achieve this?

If you'll need more information or parts from my code, I'll update the question with the required information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate Validator clearly doesn't support that. For sure the `validation.xml` needs to be in the jar. We could maybe support having the `file:` prefix to point to external constraint mappings. I would accept a patch if you were willing to work on that.

Not sure about the resource bundles though so that would be an half baked solution for you.

I wonder if you could just pass a carefully crafted class loader that can load resources from your external location (and delegate everything else to the standard class loader) and use `externalClassLoader(ClassLoader)` to pass it to HV when configuring the `ValidatorFactory`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer & clarifying that it's not possible right now.  

I'm still a novice developer and I'm not familiar with class loaders at all, so I think I'll try something else to achieve my goal. Thank you for the idea though!  


I don't think I'll get around to develop a patch for this function in the near future. I barely code in my free time and I don't think my superiors would like me to do this at work ;)  
If it itches me to contribute to an open source project in the future, I'll might get back to it.